# Hi, I am importing some csv files. I would like to consolidate but delete the totals and add a new total

Tags: r, rbind

I am importing some csv files.

Once loaded the dataframes have totals.

I want to consolidate all the dataframes into one.

But delete the total row from each individual file and add a new total row that is of all dataframes combined.....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1rQU.png)

Comment: Dput

df1=structure(list(Name = c("row1", "row2", "row3", "Total"),
               Col1 = c(10,20,30),
               Col2 = c(15,30,45),
               Col3 = c(30,60,90)),
               row.names = c(NA,      -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2=structure(list(Name = c("row1", "row2", "row3", "Total"),
               Col1 = c(5,10,15),
               Col2 = c(8,15,23),
               Col3 = c(15,30,45)),
          row.names = c(NA,      -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: The example data you provided doesn't match the image you posted. Does the data look  like it does in the image i.e. total at the bottom of each row?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Yes, the image is correct - total at the bottom of each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to delete the last row of each data.frame to remove the totals. You can do that by using `head(df, - 1)`. To combine data.frames, you can use `rbind.data.frame` function. Finally, to add a new total, you can use `rowSums(df)`.